# Find a pair with the given difference in Python list using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose, we have a list like below and I want to find the pair whose difference should be 10. we should have a function which will take list(l) and difference(10) and print the pair as (12,22). We should use dictionary to get that. 
l = [6,22,4,1,12,45,3]

Comment: Ok. What's your question? This isn't a site to do your homework for you. You need to try yourself, and ask a specific question regarding a problem you ran into.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered.

Comment: I think I have explained my problem above. What is wrong with learning new things and doing things differently.

Comment: @Debaprasad You explained the general problem, but not what your actual question is, or what you've done to try to achieve it already. This appears to be a homework dump. Questions should show what you've already tried, and what failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [6,22,4,1,12,45,3]
ld = {v: True for v in l}
difference = 10
diff_pairs = [(v, difference + v) for v in l if (difference+v) in ld]
```

hope this code snippet helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Pramod !